# How to get value from Datetime-local in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("#datetime-local").val()
```

I am unable to get value from datetime-local.

Comment: Post your markup

Comment: It would be easier for us to help if you show us your markup also

Comment: What are you getting? undefined? is the id correct which you are using here? i.e. 'datetime-local'?

Comment: Can u plz post ur markup ? Have u audited your Id here, i mean is #datetime-local apt ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For getting the DateTime value you can just use JavaScript as the follow:

```
var date = new Date();
alert(date);
```

This will show you an alert with the current datetime value. Then you can use it for showing it or apply some logic with it.

Take into account that this value doesn't refresh until you do again the `new Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.val()` method of jQuery is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

I think you might be using it on some other type of element which is causing this behaviour.

Refer to the [jQuery documention of .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score -1):

You can go for the following :

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
```

creating the Date object , which will console the current local date.

Other ways to use instead of Date() :

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(date string)
```

Example :

```
var d = new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 30, 0);
var d = new Date(1000);
new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00");
```